# Why can't Selenium (Python) find link on page with link text?

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the snippet of HTML I am drawing from:

```
<div class="exportlinks">
Export options:
<a href=[link]>
<span class="export CSV">CSV</span>
</a>
|
<a href=[really secret link here]>
<span class="export excel">Excel</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Here is the snippet of code that I am trying to use to do so:

```
exportToExcel = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Excel")
exportToExcel.click()
```

I had also tried to find the element by class name (export excel) to no avail.

Heck, I even tried to retrieve both links via find elements by class ("exportlinks") and then select from that list the one I wanted, but it returned an empty list.

Am I missing something here? Does it have to do with the fact that the text and class are in a ? Or the fact that this snippet of HTML is pretty deep in the rest of the HTML of the page?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @Jayjayyy It does not! But good thought

Comment: it would help to describe what _doesn't work_ means in each case. Are there error messages? What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it dynamically generated you have to use `WebDriverWait`

```
exportToExcel = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    lambda d: d.find_element_by_link_text("Excel")
    # lambda d: d.find_element_by_css_selector('.export.excel')
)
exportToExcel.click()
```

Or if it in `iframe` switch to it

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_***("....")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
exportToExcel = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Excel")
exportToExcel.click()
```

Comment: Ah, I think we're on the right track with the iframe thing, but it's not quite an iframe. I can right click and "See Frame" which seems to indicate that it's a table based on Java? A .jsp file? Any clue how to access that?

Comment: see the answer just find the `iframe` element or post how is the code for the `<iframe>` in your question

Comment: I believe you're right! The only problem now is that I can't click on the link because it is at the bottom of the page. Do you know how to scroll inside the iframe? I've searched it a couple times and can't figure it out.

Comment: after switch to frame add `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

Comment: Darn... doesn't work. No error, but it doesn't scroll. Maybe the iframe is not what I should be selecting.